# WPF Input Method Editor

Tags: wpf, ime

I'm trying to enable the IME in WPF... which works for some textboxes but not the one I actually need it for. I do the following in XAML

```
InputMethod.IsInputMethodEnabled="True" InputMethod.PreferredImeConversionMode="Native" InputMethod.PreferredImeState="On"
```

I have a custom on-screen keyboard, the textbox has focus, and keys can be pushed on the screen and send the appropriate letter to the textbox. But when setting this above xaml to the textbox in this custom keyboard, the candidate window doesn't display at all, instead a strange small black control appears on the top left of the screen with a text box and a green arrow which has a caption of "Enter". Any text pressed on the keyboard goes to that small black control without showing the text, but after pressing enter, that text appears in my keyboard.

Ultimately I'm trying to incorporate simplified Chinese. Again, this works perfect on every other textbox but the one I actually need it for, being the custom onscreen keyboard.

Any thoughts? I'm really stuck with this.

Cheers.

**UPDATE**

This is the image I see, don't scroll down, it's the black little control with the green arrow.
http://babelstone.blogspot.ca/2010/05/prototyping-tangut-imes-or-why-windows.html

Comment: After pressing a letter and then a number "2", the Chinese input is displayed in the textbox, so it is working, but candidate window doesn't look anything like it should and doesn't show me the options. And it's in the top right corner, but allows me to drag it around, very strange, I've never seen this before.

Answer (score 0):

So I've been looking for a different design of the IME, Notepad seems to show something different. But I eventually got the little black box control to work and display what I'm actually typing. Moved xaml to code behind and it started working.

Comment: hi I am facing a similar issue, can you tell what was your solution